# Why would executing directly from the console operate in bulk vs. one at a time when multiple clicks are executed in a row using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code that works well when I run it just one line at a time in the Javascript console in Chrome.

```
function execClick(x, y) { 
    jQuery('#game').children()[0].children[x].children[y].click();
};

execClick(1,4);  
execClick(3,2);  
execClick(2,6); 
execClick(0,0);
```

However, when I paste the whole thing as a block, it fails to work (usually only doing the last one. On the page, when I execute a click, the content of the div is swapped out for another piece of content. Under the hood, the game I'm playing uses Vue.js. I'm looking for two things:

1. One, is there a hack that I can do here just to get going? I'm thinking something like setTimeout() but that doesn't seem like it's working.
2. What could be going on behind the scenes that would cause this difference?

I had assumed it was just a timeout/waiting thing, but that doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: it isn't a timeout/waiting thing, it seems to be an Async thing that you want to manipulate as if it were a Synchronous thing. _**What could be going on behind the scenes that would cause this difference?**_ : Something asynchronous. Research Promises and Asyn/Await.

Comment: interesting - i've now gone directly to manipulating the Vue object, and it still has the same problem. There's definitely a wait for callback thing happening behind the scenes, but I can't figure out how to properly wait for the callback to finish. Can I attach something to the Vue object to wait for a specific function to finish?

Comment: Can you show how you use vue in this example? Also, why are you doing a click? Can you just call the function that swapps the content directly?